# value of case class parameter is not a member of Serializable

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, case-class

I am trying to build a validator for Json structure, and at this point I already have something as follows:

Reads definitions

```
case class SubTaskConfigElement(name: String)

case class MultiSelectConfig(subTasks: Seq[SubTaskConfigElement])

implicit val subTaskConfigElementReads: Reads[SubTaskConfigElement] =
    (__ \ "name").read[String](minLength[String](0)).map(SubTaskConfigElement)

implicit val multiSelectConfigReads: Reads[MultiSelectConfig] = (
    (__ \ "subTasks").read[Seq[SubTaskConfigElement]]
).map(MultiSelectConfig)
```

And I have a unit test as follows:

```
val configJson = Json.parse(
                """
                  |{
                  |    "subTasks": [
                  |        { "name": "Sub Task 1" },
                  |         { "name": "Sub Task 2" },
                  |        { "name": "Sub Task 3" }
                  |    ]
                  |}
                """.stripMargin)

            val valid = configJson.validate[MultiSelectConfig] getOrElse JsError

            logger.info(valid + "")

            valid must beAnInstanceOf[MultiSelectConfig]
            valid.subTasks must beAnInstanceOf[List[SubTaskConfigElement]]
```

In the last line of the test I am getting an error when I execute the test:

```
[error] /app/process-street/test/validation/widget/config/FormFieldWidgetSpec.scala:29: value subTasks is not a member of Serializable
[error]             valid.subTasks must beAnInstanceOf[Seq[SubTaskConfigElement]]
```

IntelliJ also identifies it as a problem with: "Cannot resolve symbol subTasks"

Why is it happening? What so I miss?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
val valid = configJson.validate[MultiSelectConfig] getOrElse JsError
```

The type of `valid` is inferred as `Serializable`, because that's the common parent type of `MultiSelectConfig` and `JsError`.  Both are case classes and case classes automatically inherit from `Serializable.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation, I already understood which line is a problem, just didn't know why is it happening.

Comment: @ShurikAgulyansky When you use `a getOrElse b` the resultant type will be the nearest parent type that `a` and `b` have in common. If they are the same types, all good, but in your case, in the `val valid` statement, they are not the same, so the type is `Serializable`. Instances of `Serializable` don't have a member called `subTasks`, which is why you get the error. As an alternative to `getOrElse`, `validate` returns a `JsResult` which you could possibly pattern match as described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson).